# Is there a way to snapshot a process at a certain time point and then always restart at that time point later on (for debugging purpose)?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, process

Assume the following debugging scenario (I have experienced): We want to debug a huge C++ program. When there is no bug, it takes about an hour to run the entire program. In the program, the first 40 minutes of the program have been verified and are guaranteed without any issues. On the other hand, the last 20 minutes of the program are under development. In order to debug the last 20 minutes, we have to constantly re-run the program. After it finishes the first 40 minutes then we can start to debug. Essentially, it means that every debug run takes at least 40 minutes. It dramatically reduces the efficiency of debugging the program.

I know that we could manually do it by dumping out the results of the first 40 minutes and then start from that. However, this is not efficient. For example, what if we want to debug the program after 50-minute mark. We have to redo the manual work. Therefore, I'm wondering whether there is an **automatic** way to snapshot the process at the 40-min mark. If that is possible, we could restart the process again and again from the saved snapshot. It could save a lot of time. Assume there is such a C/C++ library. What I hope it looks like is as follows:

```
foo(); // takes 40 mins
snapshot(); // provided by the library
bar(); // under development
```

The function `snapshot()` could snapshot the entire process at the time it is called to the disk. Then we could somehow load this snapshot later multiple times. When the snapshot is launched, the program will automatically start right after `snapshot()`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: The OS is expected to be Linux or Windows.

Comment: Do you think maybe it would help to say what operating system you are using?

Comment: On a Unix system, you can insert code in the process to call `fork` and then, in one of the resulting processes, to suspend itself in some way (e.g., just wait for user input by calling `getchar()`). When you are ready to proceed with it, you can attach to it with a debugger and resume it. This could be done multiple times; the parent can just fork repeatedly while you debug one child after another.

Comment: First thing was coming to my mind was a virtual machine snapshot, but when you recompile you create a binary image that is probably different, so I don't see how a process generated from the old binary can be used to debug the new binary. I'd work on the status variables+boundary conditions.

Comment: Another guess: Use a serialization library? Of course, this won't store the RAM and CPU states.

Comment: https://rr-project.org/

Comment: do you want to modify `bar`, then resume with a snapshot from an executable without taht modifications?

Comment: It would be difficult to restore the process IDs and the states of all the open files from a snapshot.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The OS is expected to be Linux (I'm using Ubuntu) or Windows. I think using fork is a good idea for Linux though you have to keep the parent process alive.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't expect this could be possible, because if we modify the implementation we have to recompile the program, right? Still, if it is possible to do it, please let me know and I would be much happier.

Comment: Any suggestions on Windows? @AlanBirtles Is there also an alternative rr-debugger for Windows?